# How to change color of buttons created dynamically inside forEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to change the colour of different buttons with different color inside swiftUI forEach statement. The colour of other buttons shouldn't be changed when changing a button color. How can I achieve this? My code looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColorModel: Identifiable {
    let value: Color
    let id = UUID()
}
let colors = [
    ColorModel(value: Color.orange),
    ColorModel(value: Color.green),
    ColorModel(value: Color.blue),
    ColorModel(value: Color.red),
    ColorModel(value: Color.yellow),
    ColorModel(value: Color.gray),
    ColorModel(value: Color.pink),
]
let totalButtons: Int = 10

struct ContentView: View {
    func updateSelectedButtons(value: Int) {
        if self.selectedButtons.contains(value) {
            if let index = self.selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value) {
                self.selectedButtons.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            if self.selectedButtons.count < 7 {
                self.selectedButtons.append(value)
            }
        }
    }
    @State private var selectedButtons: [Int] = [Int]()
    @State private var colorIndex: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0 ..< totalButtons) { index in
            Button(action: {
                self.updateSelectedButtons(value: index)
                self.colorIndex += 1
            }) {
                Text("  ")
            }
            .background(self.selectedButtons.contains(index) ? colors[self.colorIndex].value : Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Comment: I have updated the descriptions and code is there. pls check @Asperi

Comment: @RoshanChamlagain What do you mean by *The colour of other buttons shouldn't be changed when changing a button colour*? Currently when you select a button you change the colour of all selected buttons to some colour. Do you want to change only the colour of one button only? How do you choose the colour? Please elaborate more on your expected behaviour.

Comment: @pawello2222 Actually i want to color the buttons as colors array above. For eg: if a user first selects any button  then the color of that button should be organe, and if the user selects another button then it should be green and so on. The user can select upto 7 buttons and if 7 different buttons are selected, then they should have 7 different color. The problem in the code above is that if a user first selects any button, then color of that button is orange and if selects 2nd button, then both becomes green. Thanks :)

Comment: @pawello2222 I have posted as separate question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759699/how-to-change-background-of-buttons-with-different-color-when-clicking-the-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedButtons = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<totalButtons) { index in
            Button(action: {
                self.updateSelectButton(value: index) // <- on tap update selection
            }) {
                Text("Button \(index)")
            }
            .background(self.selectedButtons.contains(index) ? colors[index].value : Color.white) // <- if index is selected set color 
        }
    }

    func updateSelectButton(value: Int) {
        guard value < colors.count else { // <- make sure you don't go outside the `colors` range
            return
        }
        if let index = self.selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value) {
            self.selectedButtons.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            self.selectedButtons.append(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came again, What if have 20 buttons and I can only select 5 colors ? The above code works only if the buttons and colors count is same. Thanks

Comment: @RoshanChamlagain This is a different question. Please create another question and describe your new problem - I'll be happy to help you there :)